# Formatting javascript error (works in Word but nothing else)

Tags: javascript, text

I have an answer posted on this website.  If I copy the code in the text field it does not work. However, if I paste the code into a word document and copy it back in, it works.  I tried in notepad and google docs and it didn't work, but for some reason, word fixes it.  Any idea why?

https://learningmathwithcoding.weebly.com/project-22-range-of-four-dice.html

```html
<div>
   <div>
   <textarea id="box" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Your Code Here:" cols="65"></textarea>
<textarea id="box2" rows="10" cols="65" placeholder="Results Shown Here"></textarea>

  <br>
  <button style="width: 2cm;height: 1cm;" id="execute">Execute</button>
 <canvas id="canvas" height="85" width="500">
  <script>
  document.getElementById('execute').onclick = function() 
{ 
r = randomInt(0,5);
proportion = 0;

var truth = 0;
for (let trial = 1; trial <= 100000; trial++)
{
var a = randomInt(1,6);
var b = randomInt(1,6);
var c = randomInt(1,6);
var d = randomInt(1,6);
var high = a;  if (b>high) high = b; if (c > high) high = c; if (d > high) high = d;
var low = a;  if (b<low) low= b; if (c < low) low= c; if (d < low) low= d;
var ran = high - low;
if (ran ==r) truth++;
}
truth = truth/100000;

try{
eval(document.getElementById('box').value); 
if(abs(proportion-truth)< .006)
{
document.getElementById('box2').value = "You got it:  The probability that the range of four dice is " + r + " = " + proportion;
}
else
document.getElementById('box2').value = "Nope:  The probability that the range of four dice is " + r + " does not equal " + proportion;
}
catch (error) {document.getElementById('box2').value = "Syntax Error";}
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
   
var r = randomInt(0,5);
var proportion;

function isClose(x,y) {return Math.abs(x-y)<.1;}

function random() {return Math.random();}
function randomInt(low, up) {var dif = up-low+1; return Math.floor(Math.random()*dif+low);}
function pow(x,y){return Math.pow(x,y);}
function abs(x) {return Math.abs(x);}
function sqrt(x) {return Math.sqrt(x);}

 </script>

</div>
```

I was expecting to be able to copy the code in the text box it work.

Comment: "it does not work" Please elaborate. Is there an error in the console? Does it give unexpected results?

Comment: if you run the code on the website, it displays syntax error (which is my try-catch exception).  But if you copy the code into a word document and then copy that and paste back in, it gives the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You have a [zero-width space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (U+200B) character at the end which causes the syntax error

Clicking backspace at the end of the code fixes the error

Seems like word removes characters like that

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't expect it to be that simple.